# Unity, Leap Motion Controller, interaction

Tags: leap-motion

I'm working on a project with the Leap Motion Controller and Unity.
I have a player (a mouse) that is walking randomly and I am trying to grab him with my hands with the Leap Motion Controller. However when my hands are detected, the player flies away and does not return.

This is my script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Leap.Unity.Interaction;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = System.Random;

public class MouseHandler: MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool enter = false;
    private Vector3 target;
    private Vector3 mouseposition;
    [SerializeField] private float stopdis;
    private InteractionBehaviour interactionbehaviour;
    [SerializeField] private InteractionHandler interactionhandler;

void Start()
{
    target = transform.position;
    interactionbehaviour = GetComponent<InteractionBehaviour>();
    interactionbehaviour.enabled = false;

    mouseposition = transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(mouseposition, target) < stopdis)
    {
        float x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, -8f);
        float z = UnityEngine.Random.Range(4f, -4f);
        target.x = x;
        target.z = z;
        //print(target);
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(mouseposition, interactionhandler.rightpalmposition) < 0.1f)
    {
        print("hi");
        interactionbehaviour.enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        mouseposition = transform.position;
        mouseposition = Vector3.Lerp(mouseposition, target, 0.05f);
        transform.position = mouseposition;
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the Interaction Behaviour of the Leap Motion Controller, but I am not sure..